# How "yes" inside the ELSE get printed when there is no IF statement for to that else?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How this "yes" getting printed?? hello will be printed once(for i==3) but print("yes")
 giving no error even there is no if statement for that else.

CODE:

```
for i  in range(5):
    if i == 3:
       print("hello")
else:
   print("yes")
```

Comment: You're using a `for-else` loop here not `if-else`. :)

Comment: My +1 to the asker as it is not obvious to search for the `for-else` in the doc. Giving it -1 means you forgot your own learning path, in my opinion.

Comment: Good point pepr and AFAIK python is one of the few languages to have something as a for-else loop. I only discovered this because someone suggested using a `for-else` loop in another question.

Answer (score 7):

The `else` branch of a `for` loop is *always* executed unless the loop was broken out of (with a `break`). Quoting the [`for` statement documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> When the items are exhausted (which is immediately when the sequence is empty), the suite in the `else` clause, if present, is executed, and the loop terminates.
>
> A `break` statement executed in the first suite terminates the loop without executing the `else` clause’s suite.

If you wanted the `else` to be part of the `if` statement, indent it to the same level:

```
for i  in range(5):
    if i == 3:
       print("hello")
    else:
       print("yes")
```

and it'll be executed for every iteration except where `i == 3` is true.

Comment: Else is not inside for loop(in the original question).It is uotside the for loop .

Comment: @user2331262: No, exactly. It is paired *with* the loop.

Comment: This code is correct but if you remove else from the foor loop and place it immediately after for loop then "yes will get printed Now the question is Why that yes getting printed??"

Comment: @user2331262: because you ran a `for` loop and it completed.

Comment: @user2331262: Look carefully at the quoted documention: *When the items are exhausted [...] the suite in the `else` clause [...] is executed*.